# Typescript: Use Generic Types for each Record-Item

Tags: typescript, generics, record, zod

I have a TypeScript problem that I'm stuck on. I've solved part of the problem, but I don't understand the solution, which is making it impossible for me to solve the next problem.

Given the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  z,
  type ZodObject,
  type ZodRawShape,
  type ZodSchema,
  type ZodType,
} from 'zod'

type CreateFieldType<S extends ZodType, P extends ZodObject<ZodRawShape>> = {
  schema: S
  props?: P
  component: (props: { field: z.infer<S>; props: z.infer<P> }) => JSX.Element
}

type CreateFormStoreProps<R extends Record<string, ZodSchema>> = {
  [K in keyof R]: CreateFieldType<R[K], ZodObject<ZodRawShape>>
}

export const createFormStore = <R extends Record<string, ZodSchema>>(
  createFormStoreProps: CreateFormStoreProps<R>
) => {
  return createFormStoreProps
}

const formStore = createFormStore({
  name: {
    schema: z.string(),
    props: z.object({ type: z.string() }),
    component: (data) => {
      const field = data.field // string
      const props = data.props // { [x: string]: any }, but should be { type: string }

      return <div />
    },
  },
})
```

The createFormStore function is passed an object that contains two types, which are supposed to be used in the component callback function within the Record-Item itself. (I'm not sure, but I don't think it matters that they are Zod schemas, you could replace them with 'unknown' and the problem would still persist).

In the component function, both field and props are passed as keys. However, field is magically type-safe, while props is not.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make both fields and props type-safe?

I've tried many things, but nothing has worked. It might also be helpful to explain why the generic Record<string, ZodSchema> results in fields being type-safe, even though it doesn't extend the CreateFieldType type.

https://github.com/colinhacks/zod